# Решите пожалуйста задачу на Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, информатика

Вам дано количество лекций и пары: индекс лекции — индекс лекции, которую предварительно нужно прослушать. Например, парой чисел 0 1 будет записан факт того, что предварительно нужно прослушать лекцию 1, чтобы понять лекцию 0.
Необходимо выяснить, можно ли провести все лекции так, чтоб все всё поняли.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Выполните [топологическую сортировку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Можешь пожалуйста показать как это в коде сделать ?

Comment: Нет, Петька, языков я не знаю ©Чапаев.   Нужно внимательно прочитать о данной сортировке, а код найти нетрудно - тем более на вики есть несколько ссылок

Comment: пожалуйста, либо переделайте ваш ответ в комментарий, либо дайте более подробный ответ.